# Question regarding output shown after converting nanoseconds to seconds

Tags: java, timeunit

I'm having trouble understanding the output generated by the code below.

The code segment:

```java
        long startTime= System.nanoTime();
        //method that I am measuring.
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();
        long elapsedTime = endTime - startTime;
        double seconds = (double)elapsedTime / 1_000_000_000.0;

        System.out.println(seconds+"secs");
```

One of the outputs that I got:

```java
 1.397E-4 secs
```

Answer (score 1):

`1.397E-4` is the same as `0.0001397`